# how to make use fake ui permanent in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc, video-recording

I have made an application to record a video by following this steps : https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC,

I want access to allow the camera always 'allow',
i've tried bypass the allow permission in popup allow webcam use start chrome --use--fake-ui--for--media-stream and it's work for me, but when i closed my chrome and then i opened chrome again , the popup permission allow webcam still showing, 
what's the solution?

Comment: As a user I do not want any app using my camera/audio without my permission... I suspect most other users feel similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you serve your application from an `https` domain, Chrome will remember the user's answer to the permissions dialog after the first use, so if they use it once, permission is granted (they click "allow"), the next time they use it, permission will be granted automatically and they won't be shown the pop up again.